# Order Decimal Values in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a varchar data type column.
The data in it is like 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.1.1, 8.3.1, 8.10, 8.12, 8.1.2 etc.
I want to order this data like

```
8.1
8.1.1
8.1.2
8.2
8.3
8.3.1
8.10
8.12.
```

I have already tried the following :

```
SELECT LEN(COL)AS SORT,COL FROM #TEMP ORDER BY LEN(COL),COL
```

This gives me the out put like

```
8.1
8.2
8.3
8.10
8.12
8.1.1
8.1.2
8.3.1
```

Help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Are the number of decimal points fixed or can they vary?

Comment: this isn't decimal at all

Comment: Its a varchar data type column containing string, i have extracted these values from that column. The decimal points are not fixed

Comment: Martin Smith.. Thanks..that is what i was looking for

Answer (score 6):

The values represented are similar to  `Hierarchy` .So first convert the values to [hierarchy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) and then perform the sort operation

```
SELECT LEN(COL)AS SORT,COL FROM #TEMP
Order by convert(hierarchyID,'/' + [Col] + '/')
```

In Hierarchy each level is differentiated by `/` which basically separates parent from child

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cca1c/2)

Comment: Will the hierarchyID work with SQL Server 2005 ??

Comment: Nope it won't work. It was introduced from `sql server 2008` onwards

Comment: +1, it should be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(col1 varchar(50))
insert into @t values('8.1'),('8.1.2'),('8.2'),('8.3'),('8.3.1'),('8.10'),('8.12'),('8.1.1')



SELECT *
FROM @t
ORDER BY CAST('/' + col1 + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)
```